Can a pulse transformer be used for single phase 120V AC isolation?
I am looking to build a ~170V DC power supply by using a full bridge rectifier on wall outlet 120V AC. After some googling I've come to learn I really need the output to be isolated as I'll be connecting other equipment to the supply and they'll all be sharing a ground plane. Ideally I would like to avoid using a bulky isolation transformer (smallest solution size possible is ideal for this application), but I am struggling to find alternatives.
Could I use a 1:1 pulse transformer for isolation from single phase 120V AC? The transformer I'm looking at in particular is SM91872AL-E from Bourns.
I'm assuming there's something fundamental I'm missing here, and that it's not as simple as finding any old transformer with 1:1 turns ratio.
Thanks!

Maybe if the AC is at a couple hundred kHz. I'm assuming it isn't, though.

The AC is at 60 Hz so definitely not! Is the problem that the pulse transformer would completely saturate at the lower frequencies? @Hearth

More than just that; see Andy's answer below. I'm pretty sure the windings would melt.

The data sheet is revealing: -
OCL (100 kHz / 0.1 V)(-40 °C to +125 °C) ............150~450 µH

OCL is the open-circuit inductance. It can be as low as 150 µH and, at 50 or 60 Hz that's an input impedance of around 0.05 Ω. Now, just imagine what current will flow when 120 volts AC is applied.
A conventional power transformer might have a 10 henry primary inductance and, the current taken from 120 volt will be about 35 mA.
I think that should answer your question.

Thank you Andy! I assumed current would be a limiting factor but had no idea how to interpret the datasheet other than it's voltage rating. This definitely answered the question
